# What does Pardot API version 4 read by email response look like?

Tags: api, pardot

The Pardot API version 4 response for "using prospects" operations looks the same as in version 3.
http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-4/prospects/#xml-response-formats
http://developer.pardot.com/kb/api-version-3/prospects/#xml-response-formats

But version 4 may or may not return multiple prospects for some operations, since multiple prospects can now have the same email address.

I'm wondering what a JSON response looks like if you do a read by email like described in the documentation:
`/api/prospect/version/4/do/read/email/<email>`

And if one prospect is returned vs multiple prospects, how the response differs.